# Postgres запрет записи одинаковых значений

Tags: postgresql

Как настроить postgres чтобы нельзя было записать одно и то же несколько раз. причем есть порядка пяти полей, они будут одинаковыми, а 6е поле - timestamp(now()) т.е. оно будет меняться

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Unique Indexes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/indexes-unique.html)

Comment: мне скорее триггер нужен

Comment: CREATE TABLE example (
       a integer,
       b integer,
       c integer,
       UNIQUE (a, c)
     );

это оно?

Comment: у меня уже есть база как поменять сейчас?

Comment: использую pgadmin, ems sql lite for pg

Comment: http://joxi.ru/BvxdU_3JTJDuZNkkIY0 Я думаю триггер не обязателен.Я использую adminer http://www.adminer.org/

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE "SC_Tag"."T_TagData" ADD CONSTRAINT uni UNIQUE ( 
 "F_TagName_ID",
 "F_Value",
 "F_Date",
 "F_ConvertedValue");
```